# Match text in selector with ConfigParser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to add a config to my ini file e.g 'Title Heading Title' so that it clicks  **a > div.title** if it matches the value without having to manually hard-code it into python? If not is there any other way to achieve it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

browser.get(config['default']['url'])
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("'a > div.title' and contains(text(), 'Heading Title' )]").click()
```

Comment: You see how you're getting the url from your config? Put `"a > div.title"` in your ini so that it's retrieved with `config['title']['heading']['title']` or something like that. Let me know if I didn't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't explain myself properly. I want to put 'Heading Title' in the config and if the text content on the page/div matches the one from the config file, then click it.  'Title' being the text content.

Comment: Try `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("'a > div.title' and contains(text(), '{}' )]".format(config['your_key'])).click()`. String formatting is the way to go for this kind of thing.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work am i formatting it correctly?
Config `[default] title = 'Event One'`

Script `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("'a > div.title' and contains(text(), '{}' )]".format(config['default']['title'])).click()`

Comment: In what way does it not work? Specificity helps us.

I see that your string formats as `'a > div.title' and contains(text(), ''Event One'' )]` with double single-quotes, which are probably invalid. You need to remove the single quotes in your INI for the string to format the way you want.